# Gradient of distance metric

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering a distance d(x,y) = $d_A(x,y)$ defined in form:
$\|x-y\|_A = \sqrt{(x-y)^TA(x-y)}$
where A is matrix (positive semi-definite).

Let $f=\|x-y\|_A$, so i want to calculate
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial A}$

Idea is to minimize function by gradient method so partial derivation is needed. 
What would be the answer?
Thanks.

Comment: So, $A$is a matrix?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention it, yes A is matrix.

Comment: I presume a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have employing the chain rule ($z=x-y$)
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial A_{kl}}= \frac{1}{2f} \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{kl}} z^T A z.
$$

We find the remaining derivative, by expanding $z^T A z$ in components and using $\partial_{A_{kl}} A_{mn} = \delta_{km} \delta_{ln}$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{kl}} z^T A z
 = \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{kl}} \sum_{mn} z_m A_{mn} z_n
 = z_k z_l.
$$

Putting everything together, we have obtained
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial A_{kl}}= \frac{(x_k-y_k) (x_l-y_l)}{2 f}.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for quick response, appreciate that :] One question though, what kl means exactly?

Comment: @mko: $kl$ refers to the two indices of the matrix; e.g., if you take the partial derivative with respect to the entry $A_{12}$ (first row, second column) then $k=1$ and $l=2$.

Comment: Thanks again. I have more questions to ask if i may: 1.) why is f (in the first expression) in denominator? (is it because of sqrt?) 2.) will the derivative be different if x,y are vectors? (i suppose not)

Comment: 3.) if the distance is squared: $\|x-y\|^2_A$, the final derivative would be same but *2?

Comment: @mko: yes, the $f$ is in the denominator because of the $\sqrt
{}$. If you take the derivate of $f^2$ then you obtain the final result without the denominator (that is $(x_k-y_k)(x_l -y_l)$).